# How do I install Keras to base(root) environment?

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am using Anaconda Navigator. I am trying to install Keras to the base(root) environment. I have a second environment called Miniconda3. This was set up when I installed Miniconda. I have tried to install keras using:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

When I look in the navigator Keras is installed in the Miniconda3 environment but not the base environment so when I try to import any of the keras modules in IPython I get 'module not found error'. Whenever I go back to the Anaconda prompt and try to install Keras again it says it is already installed. It even tells me that Theano is set as back end which is what I want. Theano is installed in the base environment and works fine in Ipython.

Thanks in advance for any ideas on this problem.

Comment: which one is your default system python that from miniconda or from anaconda navigator?

Comment: Hi, sorry, how do i find out what my default system python is? I think it is the one from Navigator, as I open Jupyter lab from navigator.

Comment: in terminal type python

Comment: This is what I get:
(base) C:\Users\mtrig>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:21:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: okay try **pip install keras**

Comment: Says requirement already satisfied...

(base) C:\Users\mtrig>pip install keras
Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\mtrig\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\mtrig\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\mtrig\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\mtrig\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\mtrig\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras)

Comment: seems like it is already there

Comment: try using jupyter notebook seems the one u are using is from a different version

Comment: Nope, still get module not found error :-(

Comment: did u put it in path?

Comment: Sorry, how do i do that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: Ok, I think the problem was that I had Anaconda and Miniconda installed. I've deleted mini, so I can now control my environments from the command line and keras has installed ok. Thanks for your help, Simbarashe :-)

Comment: Welcome @Miraz, happy coding